# IE9 quirks mode issue Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, wordpress-theming

When viewing this site http://hefrani.com/ on IE9 its showing issue . Its working fine in all browser.

Its showing issue only in IE9

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You have a style element before the doctype, which throws IE into quirks mode.

Additionally, check this page for more errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhefrani.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0